# Nifi getting error in ExecuteScript

Tags: java, python, json, apache-nifi

I have been trying to extract data from nifi's ExecuteScript Processor and attach to the flowfile as attributes. I have tried many sources out there, especially the one at funnifi blog of Matt Burgess.

Following is my code

```
import json
import java.io
from org.apache.commons.io import IOUtils
from java.nio.charset import StandardCharsets
from org.apache.nifi.processor.io import StreamCallback

originalFlowFile = session.get()
text = IOUtils.toString(originalFlowFile)
log.info(text)

if(originalFlowFile != None):
    event = json.loads(text)
    if (event['true'] == 'Y'):
        flowfile = session.putAttribute(flowfile, "true", "Y")
    elif (event['src'] == 'ONE' ):
        allAttributes = { "true": "N", "src": "ONE" }
        flowfile = session.putAllAttributes(flowfile, allAttributes)
    elif (event['src'] == 'TWO' ):
        allAttributes = { "true": "N", "src": "TWO" }
        flowfile = session.putAllAttributes(flowfile, allAttributes)
    session.transfer(flowFile, REL_SUCCESS)
    session.commit()
```

This is in python. The flowfile data IS a JSON. Still, I am unable to parse it.

The INFO part is the output of

```
text = IOUtils.toString(originalFlowFile)
```

[image: The error I am getting]

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

p.s. I am unfamiliar with python

Test data

```
{
  "true":"N",
  "src":"ONE",
  "var1":"value1",
  "var2":"value2"
}
```

UPDATE

My updated code, which still does not work:

```
import json
import java.io
from org.apache.commons.io import IOUtils

originalFlowFile = session.get()

if(originalFlowFile != None):
    inputStream = session.read(originalFlowFile)
    text = IOUtils.toString(inputStream)
    log.info(text)
    event = json.loads(text)
     if (event['true'] == 'Y'):
        flowfile = session.putAttribute(flowfile, "true", "Y")
    elif (event['src'] == 'ONE' ):
        allAttributes = { "true": "N", "src": "ONE" }
        flowfile = session.putAllAttributes(flowfile, allAttributes)
    elif (event['src'] == 'TWO' ):
        allAttributes = { "true": "N", "src": "TWO" }
        flowfile = session.putAllAttributes(flowfile, allAttributes)
    session.transfer(flowFile, REL_SUCCESS)
    session.commit()
```

Comment: error `no json object could be decoded` means you don't have a json object in flow file content. could you update your question and add: 1) a flowfile content. 2) a goal what you want to do with your script. and why you choose python when you unfamiliar with it?

Comment: I wanted to use javascript, but that is unavailable in the options! The sample data, I am adding now....

Comment: The goal is to check data, get the data points on the basis of which I want to create separate streams and add it as attributes.

Comment: I published the flowfile to a kafka stream, and it is verified that the received data is in fact in JSON format.

Comment: ecmascript - is a javascript ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Calling IOUtils.toString() on the flow file itself is likely not going to work since the flow file is not an InputStream, or Reader, or something that can be read on its own. I'm actually surprised that line doesn't produce an exception.

There are two ways you could get the content of a flow file...

The first is by getting the InputStream for a flow file from the session:

```
originalFlowFile = session.get();
inputStream = session.read(originalFlowFile);
text = IOUtils.toString(inputStream);
```

The second is by using an InputStreamCallback:

```
flowFile = session.read(flowFile, {inputStream ->
   // read the inputStream
} as InputStreamCallback);
```

Comment: Tried the first method, getting the same error that No JSON could be decoded. But I am seeing the content in kafka... the data IS JSON....I have added the updated code. The test json is same as given

Comment: So when you do log.info(text) does it print the json to nifi-app.log?

Comment: I would also recommend using the NiFi UI to investigate what is in your flow fliles. You could leave the script processor stopped, let some flow files build up in the queue right before it, then right-click the queue and do List Queue, then pick one of the entries and drill in and look at the content to make sure the json is in there.

Comment: I used NiFi UI to try to get the data, but NiFi UI just gives the metadata of the object in the queue...It is not showing the data that is in the queue, just the position, UUID, filename, size, etc...

Comment: What I think you should know it that the queue is getting filled from another processor, a SplitJson processor, where from an array I am spitting out individual objects. Thanks for your help

Comment: Okay, I got to download the file, and yes, it contains the same expected JSON....

Comment: Ok so using the first approach from above, if you put log.info(text) right after the text = IOUtils.toString(inputStream), do you see the JSON get logged to nifi-app.log?